# Python passing objects to a function

Tags: python

How can i pass object of one class to function parameters

```
class Login():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def addUser(self,User):
        pass

class User():
```

So in my code i want to pass the object of user to the addUser function of the login class? I am to Python.

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamically typed language - your method *signature* does not care about the type of the parameter. So something like:

```
class Login(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def addUser(self, user):
        user.add()

class User(object):
    def add(self)
        self.set_password()

u = User()
l = Login()
l.addUser(u)
```

would work just fine.

Comment: Ok. So the parameter can be anything we want it to be ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an instance of this class by doing

> def addUser(self,User):
>
> ```
>     myUser = User()
> ```